# PHP - access the $conn variable in another scope

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
include_once('includes/config.php');
include_once('includes/ingame.inc.new.php');
```

in my config.php file, I have this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dblogin,$dbpassword);
```

In my ingame.inc.new.php:

```
    function getSomething($id)
    {
    $sql = 'MY_QUERY';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
      echo mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the $con variable is `undefined` inside the function.

What I can do to use my $con inside the function that runs a query?

Comment: You should pass it into the function, something like `function getSomething($con, $id)`

Comment: It's not crazy that I need to pass the $conn to every function ?